# How can I farm Hunter Hellquist?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have already competed the mission "This just in" and i would like to farm Hunter Hellquist for The Bee shield. However, every time i head to his place in Arid nexus- boneyard, he is not there.

I have tried leaving the game and coming back but to no avail.

**How can  make him re-spawn?**

Comment: usually save an quitting and then returning to the same place works but since it doesn't, that enemy is probably bugging out you might want to try switching off the Xbox entirely and then maybe trying again an hour later not sure if this will work though, just a suggestion

Comment: Did you actually complete, "turn in" the quest? Hunter does not respawn until you get the quest reward, having the quest done but active is not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to : **finish the quest once** (which mean turns it in) > then every time you'll go to Arid-Nexus > head to the radio station > take the elevator > open the door > kill him > ( > find the Bee on the first try because you are so lucky) > quit your progression > restart > head to Arid Nexus (you'll probably respawn near the catch-a-ride) > Loop

I took me about 1h30 to get the Bee. If he's not there try to simply restart the game, it might be a glitch. Otherwise you can go find it in lower/higher difficulty

Comment: I will try to restart the game like david said I guess maybe leave for a day then return to see is anything changed

Answer (score 0):

turn off your xbox 360 or when you get the quest kill hunter Hellquist turn it in and the save and quit then go to boneyard go to the palce were he is and he should be there save and quit when you kill him

Answer (score 0):

I found that he had a bit of time before he would respawn, so I decided to farm another legendary weapon alongside it. I decided to farm Doc Mercy and Hunter Hellquist. Infinity pistol+Bee with a few class skills that help regen shield and you'll be dominating